# Selecting texts of various inputs with mouse

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I want to get values of inputs (type text) with selecting them with my mouse, and copy their values with one single move / click of my mouse

I have that inputs :

```
<input type="text" value="one" />
<input type="text" value="two" />
<input type="text" value="three" />
<input type="text" value="four" />
```

I want to copy (in my clipboard) the text of my inputs 1 & 2 & 3 by passing my mouse over them

Not just one input ... but multiple inputs by only one move of my mouse and after that I will do Ctrl-C

Comment: not just one input ... but multiple inputs by only one Ctrl-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code, this might solve your problem

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/67shj3ov/)

```js
$('input[type=text]').mouseover(function() {
  var abtest = '';

  $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    abtest = abtest + ', ' + $(this).val();
  });

  if (abtest.indexOf(',') >= 0)
    abtest = abtest.substring(1, abtest.len);

  $('#lbltest').text(abtest);
  SelectText('lbltest');
});



function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document,
    text = doc.getElementById(element),
    range, selection;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(text);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="one" />
<input type="text" value="two" />
<br>
<input type="text" value="three" />
<input type="text" value="four" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label id="lbltest">abtest</label>
```

Comment: You need to setup jQuery in your fiddle too